# How to assign one value to multiple variables

Tags: java

I want to receive one value, which represents multiple variables. for example
I receive 110200john
This value goes directly without any code to multiple variables like

```
int x = 11
double y = 0200
string name = john
```

How can I do that ?

Can I use enum

```
enum data {
 int x ;
double y ;
string name ;

}
```

Also I am receiving the value in byte format.

Thank you for your help guys

Comment: is there any particular pattern in which you expect the input ? for this input you can split the based on character count. or write a regex pattern for the same

Comment: I recommend using arrays, collections or objects for that puprpose.

Comment: You need a delimiter between different variables

Comment: Without any code? That's not possible. You'll have to write some code for this.

Comment: can I use ENUM or structure.

Comment: @user3003395: I don't see where an enum would come in here. There's no fixed set of values in what you've described.

Comment: Thank you Jon for your help. sorry  I am new user I can't vote up for your answer

Answer (score 6):

You should almost certainly create a class to represent those three values together, if they're meaningful. I'd personally then write a static `parse` method. So something like:

```
public final class Person {
    private final int x;
    private final double y;
    private final String name;

    public Person(int x, double y, String name) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Person parse(String text) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(0, 2));
        double y = Double.parseDouble(text.substring(2, 6));
        String name = text.substring(6);
        return Person(x, y, name);
    }

    // TODO: Getters or whatever is required
}
```

This assumes that the format of your string is always xxyyyyname - basically you should adjust the `parse` method to suit, using `substring` and the various other parse methods available.

Comment: Using Scanner to parse words might be simpler ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Given the smiley, I'm not sure how serious you are - but just in case, and for the sake of future readers, my experience based on questions on SO is that `Scanner` is extremely error-prone... I try to avoid it where possible.

Comment: I would have thought Scanner would be less error prone. e.g., if you have an int or double which is a different length.  The `;)` was because you must have had a good reason not to use it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Well in the example string given, I'm assuming the fields must be fixed length - there's no obvious separator, and there's a leading 0 for the double...

Comment: Thank you. can I use enum or structure

Comment: @user3003395: Why are you obsessed with using an enum? It's clearly inappropriate. And what do you mean by "structure"? A class is a data structure in Java - it isn't like C# where there are also structs...

Comment: @user3003395 you could but it's not clear from your question as to what assumptions you can make. e.g. for an `enum` you need to know all possible combinations at compile time. Is this true?

Comment: Thank you Jon for your help. sorry I am new user I can't vote up for your answer

Comment: @user3003395: but you *can* mark Jon's answer as "Accepted". As a new user, you may want to read the short, friendly introductory [tour].